# Finding the first occurrence in 2 lists in Python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble doing this, I want to do a function that does this : I have 2 lists : `list1 = [8,6,0] and list2 = [6,0]`. I want to keep the first value that's the same between the 2 lists (6 here). Like if I had list1 = [a,b,c] and list2 = [b,c]. I'd like to keep only value b. 
I've already tried this :

```
def listFirstValue (list1,list2) :
for x in list1 :  
  for y in list2 :
    if x == y :
      break
  break
return a
```

Thank you for your response.

Comment: you could do `[i for i in list1 if i in list2][0]` (although it will raise an IndexError if there are no matches)

Comment: @Dan better to use `next()`

Comment: What if you have `list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3]; list2 = [1, 4, 5, 0]`. Which value do you want then?

Comment: @Dan For large lists, list comprehensions have a significant space overhead. Generator expressions should be better: `next(i for i in list1 if i in list2)`

Comment: As @a_guest said, it is not clear what you exactly want to get. The first value in `list1` that is also in `list2`?

Comment: Yes, the first value (in order) in list1 that is also in list2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do this with a generator comprehension using `next` to retrieve the first element in `list1` that is contained in `list2`:

```
list1 = [8,6,0] 
list2 = set([6,0])

next(i for i in list1 if i in list2)
# 6
```

---

A little safer, avoids errors in the case where no elements are contained in `list1`:

```
next((i for i in list1 if i in list2), None)
```

Comment: Yes that's why I'm using `next` @ncica

Comment: yes ,nice solution with next, I wasnt read carefully, upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

If the items in `list2` are hashable it might be good to create a corresponding set first, for faster lookups (set has O(1) membership test):

```
lookup = set(list2)
next(x for x in list1 if x in lookup)
```